# -e option not inherited by bash scripts?

Tags: bash

I thought any script launched from a bash environnement that has -e option set would inherit this -e option.
It seems it is not the case
Below, a bash subshell is launched and -e option is set , echo_set_options is a small script that just echoes its $- value

```
>( set -e; echo $- ; echo_set_options )
ehimBHs
$-=hB
```

with echo_set_options just echoing $- :

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo $-
```

I don't really understand why let -e option be inherited by subshells and not by scripts

Another question : where is it possible to find description of all flags that make $- value ?

I know that e stands for -e option, B means brace expansion , i for interactive, but what about s for instance ?
I haven't found the description of $- value

Thanks for your help !

Comment: A script runs in a whole new interpreter. Why would you think that new interpreter _would_ inherit settings from the old one? If that's how it worked, you'd never know what the execution of your scripts would work like because it would depend on the configuration of the shell they were started from; how could anyone be expected to write correct scripts, or desk-check someone else's scripts for correctness, without knowing what settings they would be run with?

Comment: The other issue is that [`set -e` breaks things](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) (enough so that in many circles its use is considered an antipattern); it's not safe to enable for scripts that weren't explicitly written with it in mind. And honestly, if you weren't already aware of the caveats written both there and in https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/, you probably don't have the background to write scripts that keep all the behavior changes enacted by `set -e` in mind (I can't keep all that background in my head myself, which is _why I don't use `set -e`_).

Comment: The "what are the valid items in `$-`?" question is a separate/unrelated one from the question in the title, so I'm voting to close this as too broad to be on-topic. That said, `help set` will show you the set of available flags.

Comment: `help set` in bash also shows the _available_ options and the letters that stand for them. Look up any flag you saw in `$-`, and you'll find it there in `help set`.

Comment: For the `B` flag, f/e, see `-B` in `help set`; for the `-H` flag see `-H` in `help set`; same for all the others.

Comment: You thought wrong, and you should be happy that this is how bash is designed. Otherwise, you would end up running a script with -e turned on, although the script was never written with this behaviour in mind. BTW, the same applies to the options which you can set via `shopt`: They aren't inherited either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subshell is *a copy of the existing process* created by `fork()`ing that process with no `execve()` syscall. Consequently, it gets all your state -- all your local variables (not just environment variables) and all your configuration flags.

A script run as a child process *is a whole new process*, created by a `fork()` followed by an `execve()`. That `execve()` completely replaces the memory image of the process with a new piece of software; environment variables survive, as do open file descriptors, but not any of the process-local memory state.